# Launching a service periodically, drains to much battery

Tags: android, battery-saver

I am designing a service that runs in the background and triggers every hour for some small work. While the app is running, the service will trigger every 10 seconds, and after app quit go back to 1 hour interval.

It is very important for my app to not be interrupted so I am using a WakefulBroadcastReceiver like recommended in the google docs on this topic.

But it seems that my app drains a lot of battery. Enough to make charging significantly slower. And battery status shows 60% on system, screen etc. and no notice of my app. So I am thinking, that my app accidentally keeps the phone awake but uses no CPU itself.

Since I want to be sure to not have this caused by my app (and drain other peoples phones) I want to ask you if there is something obviously wrong in the way I am implementing the service.

**Main Activity**

```
/*import*/
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static String versionname;
    public static int versioncode;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AlarmManager alarmMgr;
        PendingIntent alarmIntent;
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent newintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WakefulTickReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, newintent, 0);
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
                        1 * 1000, alarmIntent);

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**WakefulBroadcastReceiver**

```
/*import*/
public class WakefulTickReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while the service is
        // launching. This is the Intent to deliver to the service.
        Intent service = new Intent(context, TickIntendService.class);
        service.setAction(intent.getAction());
        startWakefulService(context, service);
    }
}
```

**IntentService**

```
/*import*/
public class TickIntendService extends IntentService {

    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public void sheduleIntent(){
        AlarmManager alarmMgr;
        PendingIntent alarmIntent;
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent newintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WakefulTickReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, newintent, 0);
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
                        60 * 60 * 1000, alarmIntent);
    }

    /**
     * The IntentService calls this method from the default worker thread with
     * the intent that started the service. When this method returns, IntentService
     * stops the service, as appropriate.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("IdleHacker","#~# starting service intent on " + intent.toString());



        if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            Log.i("IdleHacker","starting boot service intent on " + intent.toString());
            sheduleIntent();
            return;
        }

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        // Do the work that requires your app to keep the CPU running.

        // Normally we would do some work here, like download a file.
        sheduleIntent();
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        WakefulTickReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    /**
     * A constructor is required, and must call the super IntentService(String)
     * constructor with a name for the worker thread.
     */
    public TickIntendService() {
        super("TickService");
    }

}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <application>
        <activity android:name=".view.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".service.TickIntendService"></service>
        <receiver android:name=".service.WakefulTickReceiver"
            android:enabled="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
</manifest>
```

I tried to remove everything unnecessary, if something is missing, please write a comment!